# How to make corda vault query return token sum or total

Tags: corda

When using the Account and Token SDKs - I have the following function which will take in an account and tokenId and return any tokens that the given account has (token name and amount).

How can I make the vault query return the sum of the token values?

```
fun getTokenBy(
        serviceHub: ServiceHub,
        account: AccountInfo,
        tokenId: String,
        status: Vault.StateStatus
    ): List<StateAndRef<FungibleToken>> {
        val issuerParty =
            serviceHub.identityService.partiesFromName(Constants.MASTER_NODE_NAME, false).first()
        val token = Token.getInstance(tokenId)

        val issuerCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(builder {
            PersistentFungibleToken::issuer.equal(issuerParty)
        }, status)

        val tokenClassCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(builder {
            PersistentFungibleToken::tokenClass.equal(token.tokenClass)
        }, status)

        val tokenIdentifierCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(builder {
            PersistentFungibleToken::tokenIdentifier.equal(token.tokenIdentifier)
        }, status)

        val accountCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(
            status = status,
            externalIds = listOf(account.identifier.id)
        )

        val criteria = issuerCriteria.and(tokenClassCriteria).and(tokenIdentifierCriteria).and(accountCriteria)
        return serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<FungibleToken>(criteria = criteria).states
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to calculate the balance of a certain account.

1. Your method is not practical and might actually crash your node; imagine if the account had 10,000 tokens; you query the vault, you get 10,000 tokens in the result set, you loop through them (200 records at a page) and you calculate the sum as you're looping.
2. Instead, you must delegate that operation to the database, meaning you have to write a query in Corda that will translate into something like this:

   ```
   select sum(quantity) 
   from fungible_token 
   where token_type = 'USD' and issuer = 'US Mint' and holder = 'd3t0x';
   ```
3. The above query will always return 1 row, instead of getting 10,000 rows.
4. In order to achieve the above, you can use the functions that come with [QueryUtilities](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/master/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/workflows/utilities/QueryUtilities.kt) (part of the SDK).
5. Below is my solution:

```java
// Query vault for balance.
QueryCriteria heldByAccount = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria().withExternalIds(
                                 Collections.singletonList(accountInfo.getIdentifier()
                                                                              .getId()));
QueryCriteria queryCriteria = QueryUtilitiesKt
  // Specify token type and issuer.
  .tokenAmountWithIssuerCriteria(tokenType, issuer)
  // Specify account.
  .and(heldByAccount)
  // Group by token type and aggregate.
  .and(QueryUtilitiesKt.sumTokenCriteria());

Vault.Page<FungibleToken> results = proxy.vaultQueryByCriteria(queryCriteria, 
                                                             FungibleToken.class);
Amount<TokenType> totalBalance = QueryUtilitiesKt.rowsToAmount(tokenType, results);
```

6. I have some good tips in [my article](https://blog.b9lab.com/cordacon-2019-highlights-r3s-tokens-sdk-6bb12a5743bd) about Tokens SDK.